# What does it say on the back cover of "Mars, We Love You" (ed. Jane Hipolito and Willis McNelly)?

Tags: mars-we-love-you

I am doing some research work on the ways in which science fiction writers and readers kind of collaborate on approaching unreal landscapes and other environments.  There is an element of genre marketing in this study.

As part of this project, I have bought a copy of this anthology.  At some point in its history, a seller has attached a sticker that cuts right across the back-cover blurb.  I have found it impossible to remove, so I wonder whether someone might be able to provide a transcript.

This book has appeared in at least two editions, and I think with at least one variant title.  Mine is the one pictured on [this Amazon page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0515030864).  It is a Pyramid book, 1973.

Asimov gives a short introduction, so of course his name is the most prominent on the cover.  The true editors, however, are definitely Hipolito and McNelly.  The full title is *Mars, We Love You: Tales of Mars, Men and Martians*.

The rear blurb consists of three paragraphs.  The third is clear, but I need the first and second clarified, if someone can kindly help with that!

Comment: If you post the writing that's visible, it might be possible to find the full text

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?35026) the book was published in four editions (if you count the U.S. and Canadian Pyramid books as two editions), one of them titled [*The Book of Mars*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?324636).
This is from the back cover of the [Pyramid edition](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?296486) published July 1973, ISBN 0-515-03086-4:

> **MARS... THE RED PLANET**
>
> The science of today probes the secrets of the planet that
> has captivated the imagination of the masters of science
> fiction for generations.
>
> Land of "The Stranger in A Strange Land" (Heinlein);
> home of the first invaders from Outer Space (H. G.
> Wells); romantic and colorful background for breath-
> less adventure (Edgar Rice Burroughs), Mars is still a spe-
> cial planet—provocative, enticing and wondrous.
>
> The vision of an alien world created by the literature of
> Mars sparked man's first tentative steps toward absolute
> knowledge of this exotic planet. The suspicion that man
> was scrutinized by a greater intelligence led him to raise
> his own eyes to the Red Star. And if life does not now
> exist on Mars, who among us will refute that the vision
> was once a reality?
>
> **"MIND EXPANDING"**
> LIBRARY JOURNAL
>
> A PYRAMID BOOK $1.25 Printed in U.S.A.

Comment: Brilliant. Do you own this book or did you get the text from an online source?

Comment: @Richard I own it.

Comment: Beat me by 4 minutes.  Nice work, as always.  :-)

Comment: @Praxis I wasn't smart enough to think of looking for copies for sale on Ebay, so I get out my own copy.

Comment: Outstanding.  I just knew that if I left this overnight (I'm in the UK) some kind soul with bookshelves like mine would be able simply to check the thing -- and it turns out that it didn't even take that long!  Both of these splendid, near-simultaneous answers are tributes to the value of collaborative scholarship.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an image of the back cover (from an eBay [auction](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/MARS-MADNESS-6-Sci-Fi-Lot-POHL-BLISH-BRUNNER-MARS-ATTACKS-MARS-WE-LOVE-U-VG-/221566589799)):

[image: transcription below]

The text reads:

> **MARS...THE RED PLANET**
>
> The science of today probes the secrets of the planet that
>   has captivated the imagination of the masters of science
>   fiction for generations.
>
> Land of "The Stranger in A Strange Land" (Heinlein);
>   home of the first invaders from Outer Space (H. G.
>   Wells); romantic and colorful background for breathless adventure (Edgar Rice Burroughs), Mars is still a special planet—provocative, enticing and wondrous.
>
> The vision of an alien world created by the literature of
>   Mars sparked man's first tentative steps toward absolute
>   knowledge of this exotic planet. The suspicion that man
>   was scrutinized by a greater intelligence led him to raise
>   his own eyes to the Red Star. And if life does not now
>   exist on Mars, who among us will refute that the vision
>   was once a reality?

Comment: I'm on a managed network and cannot access eBay, else I would grab it.

Comment: Outstanding.  I just knew that if I left this overnight (I'm in the UK) some kind soul with bookshelves like mine would be able simply to check the thing -- and it turns out that it didn't even take that long!  Both of these splendid, near-simultaneous answers are tributes to the value of collaborative scholarship.

Comment: @CaptainCranium : Glad we could help!